# Suggestion for add-on for date-triggered emails?

Tags: ee2, email

Thought someone might have a suggestion of an existing add-on or built in EE solution.

What the client needs is a way to trigger a specific 'reminder' email sent out. The date, time, and email template, would be set in fields on the individual members entry (using members as entries).

For example, an entry called "John" could be updated by the client to trigger a reminder email to go out in 30 days, which would only go to him.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Postmaster](https://www.objectivehtml.com/postmaster) Add-Ons Email Solution will let you send emails exactly when you want.

Comment: I'd probably agree in that Postmaster will give you the greatest flexibility here.

Comment: +1 fr postmaster, it's a great addon with all types of awesome functionality.

Comment: Thanks guys, Postmaster is definitely what I would recommend too. Email support@objectivehtml.com if anyone has any questions.

Comment: Not that Justin is biased at all in his opinion. ;)